# Can I reveal a card from my hand whenever I want legally?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a rule that would make it illegal to reveal a card from my hand as an intimidation tactic or incentive strategy?

If there is not, I still might not do it (and just stick to hoping people belive me when I say it). I just want to know if I could legally reveal my Group Hug cards from my hand and show the other players in my playgroup that I have things to benefit them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can reveal cards from your hand whenever you want.

The regular comprehensive rules don't address this one way or the other, but in the [tournament rules](https://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_19feb18_en.pdf), section 3.12 entitled "Hidden Information" says

> Hidden information refers to the faces of cards and other objects at which the rules of the game and format do not allow you to look.
>
> Throughout the match, a draft, and pregame procedures, players are responsible for keeping their cards above the level of the playing surface and for making reasonable efforts to prevent hidden information from being revealed. **However, players may choose to reveal their hands or any other hidden information available to them, unless specifically prohibited by the rules.** Players must not actively attempt to gain information hidden from them, but are not required to inform opponents who are accidentally revealing hidden information.

Comment: IMO "unless specifically prohibited by the rules" (already bolded) is noteworthy since the original post speaks of benefits.  I assume 2 headed giant team rules would be an example, so any team play home brew would likely follow that rule train.

Comment: Hm, that rule seems to be self-contradictory by stating that players "are responsible ... for making reasonable efforts to prevent hidden information from being revealed" but also allowing players to "choose to reveal ... hidden information". I'm downright confused. Would it be legal for me to show my hand to one opponent but not another?

Comment: It says that you are "responsible" for keeping information hidden, but not that you are "required" to keep information hidden. I would interpret that as meaning specifically that it is considered your fault, and not your opponents', if you accidentally reveal hidden information. And that is confirmed by the last sentence.

Comment: As for revealing the information to one opponent but not the other, the tournament rules do not cover any free-for-all formats, so I would say that that issue is not addressed either way by the rules.

Comment: @NuclearWang To me, the spirit of the paragraph is: 1. don't cheat; 2. if you accidentally flash your hand at your opponent, that's not something they'll get punished for (and there's no point in punishing *you* for it, or in splitting hairs about whether it was accidental or intentional, so let's just make it a legal thing you can do)